# Running a Flutter app on the foreground 24/7

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I Have a flutter app that is supposed to be a display app for some contents besides ads for some restaurants...The app is supposed to work 24/7 and will be on andriod tablets only.

I have searched a lot and the latest thing I found was to set the app to be a system app using the following tags

```
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
```

and the premission

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

and I am using the "screen" plugin as well to keep the screen always on.
The problem now is the screen is always on and the app running without any problems for 24 and some times for 48 hours then the lock screen shows up and after unlocking the screen the app is on the foreground playing without any problems.
Is there any way to keep the app displaying always on the foreground?
or a way to disable the lock screen from appearing if it causing the issue?

Comment: Did you have a look here? => https://medium.com/stuart-engineering/%EF%B8%8F-the-tricky-task-of-keeping-flutter-running-on-android-2d51bbc60882

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Screen Pinning](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9455138?visit_id=637080373127133374-3710676579&rd=1) which requires no code.

Or you can implement [Lock task mode](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode).